# returnKeyType "next" not working

Tags: facebook, react-native

Can someone help me on this please? I have two `TextInput` fiels: email and password.

When I hit *next*, it will not focus to my password TextInput. I don't know what is wrong. I am using Android device not emulator.

Here is my code.

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="email"
  returnKeyType="next"
   blurOnSubmit={false}
  keyboardType="email-address"
  onEndEditing ={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
/>

<TextInput
  ref={(input)=>this.passwordInput = input }
  placeholder="password"
  returnKeyType="done"
  blurOnSubmit={true}
/>
```

Comment: Could you specify that does this happen on the emulator or with certain Android device?

Comment: this happen in android device

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
<TextInput                                                
placeholder="email"                           
returnKeyType="next"                                            
blurOnSubmit={false}                                     
keyboardType="email-address"                                     
onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.refs.SecondInput.focus(); }}/>  

<TextInput         
ref='SecondInput'                                                                   
placeholder="password"                                   
returnKeyType="done"                                            
blurOnSubmit={true}/>
```

it worked for me...
hope it will help you

Comment: Although this might work, it seems to be a pretty bad solution. Because then you'll have to make an object for every single input on your page. "next" is generally needed when there are multiple fields, and if you have a registration form you'll have quite a few objects and may not be the cleanest approach.

Comment: I don't understand why, but returnKeyType="next" no longer seems to work, though it used to...

Comment: Also this becomes extra complicated when multiple inputs within a flatlist.